Does delete uses free() in the background in cpp?
Here's what I know:
-Whatever has been allocated with malloc/calloc, should be deallocated with free(), and whatever has been allocated with new, should be deallocated with delete.
-free() and delete are seperate things, delete calls destructor after destroying the allocated memory, free simply deallocates the allocated memory.
So here's the thing: How does delete work in the backend, does it use free()? And may delete be implemented using free()?

new() and delete() and do not exist in C. Tag removed.

It's not guaranteed, I believe.

"...How does delete work in the backend, ..." it's depends on the implementation of the Standard library you are using.  Check the source code ( if available ).

@BoP Specifically the last paragraph of the top answer.

Side note : If you're interested in (avoiding) memory leaks, use neither of them. The use of new/delete is not recommended (unless wrapped in a datastructure)... and malloc/free is mostly for "C". Use C++'s containers like std::vector or use std::make_unique/std::make_shared. See R.10/R.11 C++ core guidelines. Can you explain why you are interested in the difference (or overlap)?

One system I've worked on used different heaps (different arenas) for malloc/free, new/delete, and new[]/delete[].

@PepijnKramer but what to use when creating and deleting class instances? cannot use vector on that?

@JuanDoe In 90% of cases you do not need dynamic allocation when creating class instances. You can simply create them as objects directly following value semantics. In the cases where you need dynamic allocation, in most cases you can use std::unique_ptr/std::make_unique for that. And then, in even fewer special cases, you use std::shared_ptr/std::make_shared. A vector can also hold std::unique_ptrs or std::shared_ptrs. In practice, except when implementing certain data structures and containers, you do not need new/delete directly in modern C++.

To answer the question, even if closed: It is not specified whether new/delete use malloc/free. They may or they may not, but it doesn't matter in the end for the user anyway, because attempting to call free on an allocation made by new or calling delete on an allocation made by malloc has undefined behavior in either case. If you created the object with new, then you must destroy it with delete.

delete calls the destructor before deallocating the memory, not afterwards.

@user17732522 thank you very much. I only just have 1 more question: Can i overload and implement new and delete so that they work with malloc/free()?

@JuanDoe In practice it is very likely that they are already implemented like that (even if they do not need to be), so doing that is pointless without specific cause. But yes, you are allowed to replace the global replaceable operator new and operator delete to obtain memory in whatever way you like as long as you follow the library requirements put on these overloads. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Global_replacements for details.

There is an example doing exactly that on the page I linked. Also note that these functions are only responsible for allocating and deallocating memory. The constructor and destructor calls are done as a separate step in the evaluation of new/delete expressions after/before they have handled the (de-)allocation by calling one of these overloads.

@user17732522 I understand, thank you so much again, I got the answer i need

@JuanDoe But just to be clear in case I misunderstood you: What I link above shows how you can force new/delete to use malloc/free. It doesn't change the fact that you must not call free on a pointer obtained from new and must not call delete on a pointer obtained from malloc.

@user17732522 Yes, i understood this too. But if i force them as in the link, I can use new and delete, but malloc/free inside, right? (still, one should never use delete on a pointer obtained from calloc)

@JuanDoe Yes, but as I said, in practice that's already likely what is happening by default. calloc is not needed in C++. If your types are properly designed so that they do not have user-defined constructors that explicitly leave members uninitialized, then simply using value-initialization will force everything to be zero-initialized, e.g. with struct MyStruct { int a, b; };, then new MyStruct() will zero-initialize the newly-created MyStruct object, even if the implicit default constructor leaves the members uninitialized. The () makes the difference.

It still makes me curious what you'd like to achieve. Do you want to take control over where memory is allocated?
